# Managing metadata for how SQL table columns are utilized

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a SQL table which will have columns added to it over time, e.g. a *Product* table where initially the columns would be *stock_count* and *product_name*.

I have another table to describe how to render these fields on the UI, for example stock count might be rendered with a numerical input field, and product_name would be rendered with a string input field.

I'd like to have another table to describe each of these fields, something like:

```
field_schema
| id |  field_name  | ui_field |
| 1  | stock_count  | number   |
| 2  | product_name | string   |
```

At first there'll only be a few *ui_field* types, but these may change later on to include dropdowns, radio button sets etc. and warrant having these types in a table of their own.

My question was, is there any straightforward method to keep the *rows* in the *field_schema* table synchronized with the columns in *Product* table? Is this the wrong approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a curious way to store things.  If you are going to have a table that describes the columns, then go all the way and use an EAV model.  That is, instead of storing columns in a single row in a table, store each value in a separate row.

This would allow you to use foreign key relationships in the EAV table to link back to descriptions of the columns.

Alternatively, you could use a [DDL trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/event-triggers.html) to ensure that when a new column is added, then the column description already exists in the field description table.  That said, any application design that requires adding columns to existing tables seems suspicious.

Comment: Due to queryability requirements, I decided not to use the EAV model since adding fields is going to be a somewhat controlled process.